# STM32CubeIde / Eclipse avoid open startup_xxx.s on every run

Tags: stm32, eclipse-cdt, stm32cubeide

Every time I've run the compiler to program de device the IDE opens the startup_xxx.s file, it's very very very annoying... Anybody knows how to stop this?

IDE: Stm32CubeIDE (Eclipse)
Device: Every device, currently STM32H7435
To reproduce: Simply click on run, the .s file it's oppened automatically, you can close it and will be oppened next time automatically

Thanks!

Comment: Please [tell how to reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than telling _"it's very very very annoying"_.

Comment: Eclipse keeps the list of open files somewhere inside `.metadata` directory. Where exactly - may depend on the version. Check if this directory is writeable by Eclipse and not blocked by some other programm. If you have reopened and saved the workspace with a differect version of Eclipse - it could have changed the metadata files, so Cube is now missing something.

Comment: @howlger I think the question itself explain how to reproduce the issue, it's obvious.. but I explained better

Comment: The question is self explaining if and only if this can be reproduced everywhere and for all kind of projects with a fresh installation of the current version of Stm32CubeIDE and a fresh workspace. Have you tried it with different projects and does this always happen?

Comment: Always yes, and can't find any option in preferences or anything...

Comment: Sorry, Can't reproduce it. Upload your minimal reproducible  entire project to GitHub and post a link here

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cause is that your cpu actually stops there. Check your debugger configuration/script for halt instructions or under "launch configuration" there's a resume conditions that could be involved because after programming the cpu is kept halted if that flag is not checked.

Comment: No breakpoints, in fact this occurs in also in release, not debugging